Nextjs middleware return null authorization bearer token
In my application I'm sending Authorization bearer token
in middleware I need to get the Authorization but it always coming null
Below are the codes
page.tsx
"use client";

import { useMemo } from "react";

async function sampleFn() {
  let accessToken: string | null = "";

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  } else {
    accessToken = "";
  }

  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST_URL}/api/v1/onboarding`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    },
  );

  return res;
}

export default async function OnBoarding() {
  // const response = useMemo(() => sampleFn(), []);
  const response = sampleFn();

  return <div>On Boarding</div>;
}

middleware.ts
import { cookies, headers } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const authorization = request.headers.get("authorization");
  console.log("authorization ->", authorization);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/onboarding/:path*", "/dashboard/:path*"],
};

as you can see I'm consoling authorization but it keeps coming null

Can you share a repo or a SandBox?

@AhmedAbdelbaset
middleware.ts - https://github.com/hiimwillow/matrimony/blob/main/src/middleware.ts
li=ogin.tsx - https://github.com/hiimwillow/matrimony/blob/main/src/app/login/page.tsx
project - https://github.com/hiimwillow/matrimony/tree/main
